# Qt: How to have QDialog follow parent

Tags: c++, qt, popup, qdialog

I hope this has not been asked before, but I have not found any thread that answers my specific question.

I have created my own QDialog class(**TagPopup**), which accurately displays the layout I have specified in its Constructor. The QDialog is created in the center of the parent - as expected - but when I move the parent the Dialog stays at its original position. I want it to always stay at the center of the parent widget regardless of where it moves.

The parent is a custom class derived from QMainWindow (**PlayerWindow**).

WindowFlags of the parent class have not been altered, but the child has to be modal, has to have Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground as an attribute and the Qt::FramelessWindowHint has to be set.

Is this only solvable by overriding the parents move event and then have the child move with it or is there a more elegant solution?

```
void PlayerWindow::open_tag_dialog(int id) {
TagPopup *dialog = new QDialog(this, GameTag::int_to_tag_type(id), (int) 1000000 * elapsed_seconds(), {this->clip->game->home_team, this->clip->game->away_team});
dialog->show();}
```

This is the method on the parent Widget which creates and shows the Dialog.

```
explicit TagPopup(QWidget *parent = 0, TagType tag_type = TagType::CUSTOM, int time = 0, vector<Team*> teams = {}, int min_height = 360) : QDialog(parent, Qt::FramelessWindowHint), BasePlayer(min_height, this){
    setModal(true);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    Qt::WindowFlags flags = windowFlags();
    setWindowFlags(flags | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

These are the first lines of the child constructor, which deal with setting the flags and attributes.

I have definitely tried removing all flags, but that also does not help.

Is QDialog for creating something like a popup? It seemed like the obvious pick. Adding the Qt::Popup flag didn't change the behaviour. It instead broke the whole layout when I passed it to the constructor and didn't add any other flags. Therefore didn't meddle with that idea for too long.

Comment: QDialog is for creating modal or modeless windows used for short-term interaction. If your popup has to be relative to a position in your mainwindow, why not create is as its child-widget instead of a dialog? This way it's position can be relative to a widget in the window. Otherwise you need catch all move and resize-events of your mainwindow, recalculate the desired position, and move your dialog. This might get ugly when the user moves the mainwindow between monitors with different resolutions.

Comment: @markus-nm Thank you for your answer. I was so dead set on it having to be its on dialog that I didnt consider just inheriting from QWidget.  Having inherited from QWidget now, it works as intended. I just have to adjust the position like you said. I have also noticed that if I turn on the Qt::Popup flag it appears on the upper left corner of the other monitor of my 2 monitor setup. The other would be considered the main display by my system.

Comment: AFAIK there is no easy way to do this, you have to react to the move event in the parent and move your other dialog manually, as you suggested.